# What pattern should I use for such tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

P.S I probably didn't quite understand the mvc principle, but I always thought that business logic should happen in models - correct me if I'm wrong


I am writing project and using the mvc pattern.
router accepts requests and passes to controller, it takes data and sends it to model. Model checks the data for validation and, if successful, works with the database. My models have very large code and mix with validation.

```
exports.modelFunction = (data) => {
// validation data ...
// working with the database
}
```

With new fixes it becomes difficult for me to read the code.
I decided to create a utils / validation / folder where I will handle all possible model validations and yes, now the code is more readable

```
exports.modelFunction = (data) => {
  const validation = validationModel(data);
  if (!validation) return {ok: false, message: 'Validation failed'}
  // working with the database
}
```

I thought that there are already some other patterns that adhere to the separation of logic and solve problems like mine. So I decided to ask you for a hint.

Comment: If this is some kind of API, forget about design patterns for a bit but instead think of 'types'. You are getting data from a client, and you need that data to confirm to a specific structure. I would want to validate this *before* it enters the model system. The model system should only deal with data that is known to be correct.

Anyway, if this is an API, considering looking into JSON Schema as it's going to be way better than manually writing validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused with data validation with business logic.

The controller is where your business logic lives. It it is the gateway to allow for model access.

If the controller decides that the user can access/modify the data, then it passes that data down to your model to do work.

Your model should validate the data and see if it has all the required attributes to work with the database. If it doesn't then it fails and is returned to your controller. If that happens, then your controller needs to do your business logic and respond back to the request with the status.